# Хорошее качество картинок

Tags: gd, php

Мне нужно уменьшить загруженную картинку и сохранить её уменьшенной, но когда я уменьшаю и ставлю качество 60, как и в фотошопе, то картинка весит меньше в 2 раза чем сохранённая с таким же качеством в фотошопе и качество хуже. Попробовал поставить качество повыше, чтобы сравнять размер картинки с размером сохранённой картинки в фотошопе, то всёравно качество было намного хуже. Может ни те функции использую? Или может какие-то фильтры надо применить? Вот функция, с помощью которой уменьшаю и сохраняю изображение:

```
function imageresize($outfile,$infile,$neww,$newh,$quality) {

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg($infile);
$im1=imagecreatetruecolor($neww,$newh);
imagecopyresampled($im1,$im,0,0,0,0,$neww,$newh,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));

imagejpeg($im1,$outfile,$quality);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($im1);
```

}

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать качество как в фотошопе, не в ущерб размеру изображения?
Или может как-то можно автоматически заставить фотошоп изменять изображения и сохранять их?

Comment: Если вы сделаете 100, то это будет вполне нормальное качество, не думаю, что имеет смысл париться. Разные другие редакторы и просмотровщики тоже сохраняют более грубо, чем фотошоп. Например, XnView или Paint.NET.

Comment: когда 100 ставишь - весит ужасно много(

Comment: входная картинка какого формата? и каковы ее оригинальные размеры?

Comment: Формата JPEG, качество 60 (может сделать входную картинку 100 качества?) Оригинальные размеры 1583х1393. Пытаюсь уменьшить до 1263х1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не получится сохранить картинку "так же хорошо как в Photoshop" с использованием PHP, если не реализовать алгоритм сохранения из Photoshop на PHP (что было бы неоправданно сложной задачей).

Для улучшения соотношения вес/качество попробуйте использовать ImageMagick.